# Oracle Bulk collect error - Ora-21700 Object Does Not Exist Or Is Marked For Delete

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to bulk collect into an associative array - ARRAY2 from another associative array - ARRAY1

Array1 is passed as a parameter from another procedure.It is also populated using bulk collect from the calling procedure

```
PROCEDURE PROC1(ARRAY1 IN T_ARRAY1 )
    ARRAY2 T_ARRAY2;
IS
    SELECT COL1,COL2
    BULK COLLECT INTO ARRAY2
    FROM TABLE(ARRAY1);
END;
```

I get the following error - Ora-21700 Object Does Not Exist Or Is Marked For Delete

**Declaration of the arrays:**

```
TYPE T_ARRAY1_REC IS RECORD(COL1 NUMBER,COL2 NUMBER,COL3 NUMBER);    
TYPE T_ARRAY1 IS TABLE OF T_ARRAY1_REC INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;

TYPE T_ARRAY2_REC IS RECORD(COL1 NUMBER,COL2 NUMBER);    
TYPE T_ARRAY2 IS TABLE OF T_ARRAY2_REC INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
```

What could be the reason for this error?

Comment: Has `ARRAY1` contain anything? How is it declared, how was it initialized, and how was it populated?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try assigning it to a variable:

```
PROCEDURE PROC1(ARRAY1 IN T_ARRAY1 )
    ARRAY2 T_ARRAY2
    tmp_ARRAY1 T_ARRAY1 := ARRAY1;
IS
    SELECT COL1,COL2
    BULK COLLECT INTO ARRAY2
    FROM TABLE(tmp_ARRAY1);
END;
```